# Blazor wasm RCL static assets are not accessible directly via url in browser in net 8

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a `.net8 blazor wasm` app with the following structure

```
| - Demo.sln
    | - BlazorWASM.csproj
    |   - wwwroot
    |       - image.png
    | - RCL.csproj
    |   - wwwroot
    |       - rclimage.png
```

when I access the above static asset, the following happens

| Action | Observation |
| --- | --- |
| `https://localhost/image.png` | ✅ This works |
| `https://localhost/rclimage.png` | This doesn't work |

I have `RCL.csproj` added as dependency to `BlazorWASM.csproj` and I can access the `rclimage.png` normally in `html` using `<img src="./_content/RCL/rclimage.png" />` but not directly in browser using `https://localhost/rclimage.png`. Please assist me on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an embedded in resource,it would be avaliable via `https://localhost/_content/RCL/rclimage.png` by default.

You could configure as below in your RCL project if you want it be avaliable via    https://localhost/rclimage.png

```
<PropertyGroup> 
 <StaticWebAssetBasePath Condition="$(StaticWebAssetBasePath) == ''">/</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```